# Why does Messaging.renderEmailTemplate() return a "Field Custom_Field__c does not exist" even when the field does exists?

Tags: error, singleemailmessage, merge-field, mail-merge

When running the code below anonymously I get a (paraphrased) error:

> "Field Custom_Field__c does not exist"

Code:

```
Id bankId = 'a1e630000000oOG';
Id contactId = '00363000009GnPE';

//verify field exists
Submission__c sub = [SELECT Id, Bank__c FROM Submission__c WHERE Id=:bankId];

//verify record exists and bank field is populated
System.assert(String.valueOf(sub.Bank__c).length()>0);

//verify record exists
System.assert([Select id from contact WHERE id=:contactId].size()==1);

String unrendered = 'Dear {!Bank__c},\n Hope you\'re doing well!';

List<Messaging.RenderEmailTemplateBodyResult> renderResults = Messaging.renderEmailTemplate(contactId, bankId, new List<String>{unrendered});

System.debug(renderResults);
```

I've made sure the whatId record exists, the field being merged is populated, and the whoId record exists (as can be seen from the assert statements).

But I get an error:

> getFieldName=Bank__c;
>
> getMessage=Field Bank__c does not exist. Check spelling.;
>
> getOffset=7;
>
> getStatusCode=EMAIL_TEMPLATE_MERGEFIELD_ERROR;

Here's the full user debug:

```
13:32:16:146 USER_DEBUG [17]|DEBUG|(Messaging.RenderEmailTemplateBodyResult[getErrors=(Messaging.RenderEmailTemplateError[getFieldName=Bank__c;getMessage=Field Bank__c does not exist. Check spelling.;getOffset=7;getStatusCode=EMAIL_TEMPLATE_MERGEFIELD_ERROR;]);getMergedBody=null;getSuccess=false;])
```

As seen in the debug log the attribute `getMergedBody` is null. I'm trying to merge text on the fly so users can send emails with their choice of fields to merge. Why am I getting this error? What does it actually mean since the field does indeed exist?

Thank you!

Edit:

The field is accessible to the running user as checked on the FLS level.

Edit 2:

This question has already been answered. To reproduce the issue in any org use this code:

```
Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, StageName FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1];
Contact con = [Select id from contact LIMIT 1];

Id oppId = opp.Id;

Id contactId = con.Id;

//verify record exists and bank field is populated
System.assert(String.valueOf(opp.StageName).length()>0);

//as per the answer, {!StageName} needs to be changed to {!Opportunity.StageName}
String unrendered = 'Dear {!StageName},\n Hope you\'re doing well!';
List<Messaging.RenderEmailTemplateBodyResult> renderResults = Messaging.renderEmailTemplate(contactId, oppId, new List<String>{unrendered});
System.debug(renderResults);
```

Comment: did you check the FLS and make sure the field is visible for the user trying to use the template?

Comment: Yes, I'm the running user. It is editable by me.

Comment: what is the unrendered list<string>? can you post the third param

Comment: it's the variable 'unrendered' which is declared on the line above that. The code compiles in my org so all parameters are present.

Comment: Duh I think I found the issue, based on your assert I assume you are trying to get the bank__c info related to Submission__c in the unrendered string. Change 'Dear {!Bank__c}...' to 'Dear {!sub.bank__c}...'

Comment: Rao you magic genius! Just switch it from 'sub.bank__c' to 'Submission__c.bank__c' and you've got a working answer. Thanks!

Comment: :) took a while to catch that, the longer you look the harder it becomes even when the error is smiling at you

Comment: ha true! I should have used the email template merger first :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the issue, based on your assert I assume you are trying to get the bank__c info related to Submission__c in the unrendered string. Change 'Dear {!Bank__c}...' to 'Dear {!Submission__c.bank__c}...'

Comment: should be the object name 'submission__c' not the apex variable 'sub'

Comment: You queried the submission__c and assigned it to sub din't you? If you use submission__c based on how you have the controller the template may still merge. If you want to get the bank__c realted to the submission where bankId = a1e630000000oOG then use sub.bank__c

Comment: sub.Bank__c throws the same "Field doesn't exist error." Submission__c.Bank__c merges as expected. Check the edit on the question to reproduce.

Comment: Ah ok, may be the templatebody expects the object api name in the merge field as shown in the documentation. I assumed the string unrender gets carried over as template body https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_renderemailtemplate.htm

Comment: I think it merges it like a UI email template https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_mail_merge_templates.htm&language=en_US&type=0 . Wish there were more documentation. In any case, thank you!